# How to SMS notifications whenever testcases fails during execution in selenium using java?

Tags: java, selenium

How to send SMS to given mobile numbers whenever a test script  fails during execution in selenium?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium cannot do that. You will need to write something like https://www.baeldung.com/java-email with your respective email-provider settings.